# Wiring the antennas together in RF link 315Mhz RX and TX

Tags: rf, transmitter, receiver

I am using a 315Mhz Transmitter and Receiver RF link kit between two arduino. What happens if I wire the antennas of both RX and TX to both ends of a 1 meter long metal wire? Will using a conductor instead of air channel affect the communication positively or negatively if it affects at all? What if its a 1m shielded wire? Will that help in noise reduction?

Comment: You will probably destroy the receiver if you try that.

Comment: Probably nothing will break depending on the design of the receiver. I would have to see a schematic before I can conclude if it will destroy anything or not. But why would you want to do this ? Why not use a wire instead ? For a distance of 1 meter these links should just work with their antenna's attached. If it does not work you have a different problem, connecting by a wire will not solve that problem.

Comment: The two modules(transmitting and receiving) got a metallic strip in between as a part of the physical structure. I was just wondering if it can be used for improving the communication. Thank you guys for your comments. Thank you @Autistic for editing my question.

Comment: What are you doing? If you need wireless transmission, what is the connecting wire for? And if you need a connecting wire, why even use wireless modules?  I mean, you are talking about 1 meter here.

Comment: Consider using coax and an atennuator.  Look at your transmit power in the spec and for any details on range or saturation - if you can't find any, estimate your typical path loss and use a similar attenuator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot to explain here, the question seems ill thought out, but I will try, and perhaps we can elaborate as you give more information.

If you are trying to design a transceiver where Rx and Tx share an antenna, then the approach you have outlined is not valid. You either need:

- Half duplex operation, using an Rx/Tx antenna switch and a proper antenna e.g. monopole.
- Full duplex operation, using a duplexer/diplexer with Rx and Tx using different frequencies and again, a proper antenna.

However, it is possible that you are talking about making a test rig where the "air channel" is replaced by a cable. If that is the case, then:

- You can connect the two using a coaxial cable.
- You *must have a large antenuator* to simulate the channel and *protect the receiver*.
- The attenuator value will depend on the Tx power and Rx max input rating listed in the "absolute maximum" section of the datasheet.
- A good starting point to avoid trouble is 50 or 60dB.

Comment: Thanks Mark, What I meant is to replace the air channel with a conductor. Yes, you answered it. Thank you.

Comment: @VishnuMohan if you edit the question a little then I will be allowed to up vote it but I cannot right now because my vote is locked. Also then there would be a clearer Q&A on the site for other people with a similar question